# How to set the http_referrer in a htaccess redirect?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-headers

I have a new domain for my site and want to forward the user to this new site.
So I set up a simple redirect in my .htaccess file likeI have a new domain for my site and want to forward the user to this new site.
So I set up a simple redirect in my .htaccess file like this:

```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.oldsite.com$
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.newsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

That works so far, but now I need to check if a user still uses the old domain and therefore I need to check the http_referrer in my php application. Unfortunately the http_referrer is not set? How can I tell my .htaccess to set the http_referrer to www.oldsite.com if the RewriteCond triggers?

Comment: Try http_referer (note the missing R - its a typo in PHP!)

Comment: I allready figured that out :) But thats not the problem, the referrer isn't set after the redirect.

Comment: _Aside:_ @davidgo That's not a typo in PHP per se - PHP simply prefixes `HTTP_` to the name of the HTTP request header - whatever that might be. The "typo" is in the HTTP request header itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr** To check to see whether `oldsite.com` is still being requested, you should check your server access logs. (Maintain a separate log, just for `oldsite.com`.)

---

> How can I tell my .htaccess to set the http_referrer to www.oldsite.com

You can't. The `Referer` HTTP *request* header is set by the User-Agent / browser. And the redirect itself is not a referrer.

For example:

1. If you type `oldsite.com` directly into the browser (direct request, ie. no `Referer` header is set) then `oldsite.com` issues a redirect to `newsite.com` then the original "no referrer" is preserved and no `Referer` header is sent.
2. If you click on a link to `oldsite.com` from `example.com` then `example.com` is set as the `Referer` (by the browser). If `oldsite.com` then issues a 301 redirect to `newsite.com` then `example.com` is *still* the referrer and this is preserved by the browser. The intermediary site that issues the redirect is effectively *hidden* from the target site.

Note that if `Referer` headers are set (and what they are set to) is also dependent on any referrer-policy that might be set on the originating site (as well as any client settings the user might have). The referrer-policy also covers HTTP to HTTPS navigation etc. (which does not send a `Referer` by default).

> **UPDATE:** I need to "react" to it. For example show the user a message like "Hey you're using an old url, please switch to a new one."

You could perhaps append an innocuous URL parameter as part of the redirect and check for this in the receiving script. This does, however, expose this URL parameter - which you would need to make sure is not picked up by search engines etc. so as not to hamper SEO (ie. set the appropriate `rel="canonical"` and/or issue a secondary redirect to remove the URL parameter - once you have logged the request).

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.oldsite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.newsite.com%{REQUEST_URI}?redirect=1 [QSA,R=301,L]
```

(The first condition that checked against `REQUEST_URI` wasn't doing anything.)

At `newsite.com/.htaccess` you could do something like the following to remove the URL parameter (this could be simplified if you have no other URL parameters). However, you might not want to perform this redirect (or perhaps "delay it" or "set a cookie") if you are wanting to display a message to the user.

```
# Remove "redirect=1" URL parameter if present
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^redirect=1(?:&(.*))?
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, makes sense to me. However I don't just need to know who is using the old url I need to "react" to it. For example show the user a message like "Hey you're using an old url, please switch to a new one."

Comment: You could perhaps set a URL parameter as part of the redirect to "inform" the receiving site? I've updated my answer.